# RecyclerView ViewHolder extending from same class has different view type (Two different ViewHolders have the same stable ID)

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

There is only one `ViewHolder` class in my `RecyclerView` adapter:

```
public static class PlayerItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public ImageView news_image;
    public TextView news_title;
    public PlayerItemViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        news_image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.news_image);
        news_title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.news_title);
    }
}

@Override
public PlayerAdapter.PlayerItemViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View item_view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.player_news_item, parent, false);
    return new PlayerItemViewHolder(item_view);
}
 @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final PlayerAdapter.PlayerItemViewHolder viewHolder, Cursor cursor) {
    Log.d("id", viewHolder.getItemId()+"");
    Log.d("view_type", viewHolder.getItemViewType()+"");
    Log.d("class", viewHolder.getClass().toString());
}
```

When I run this code:

```
08-27 15:57:03.414 19971-19971/? D/id: 0
08-27 15:57:03.414 19971-19971/? D/view_type: 1
08-27 15:57:03.414 19971-19971/? D/class: class io.github.nekotachi.easynews.ui.adapter.PlayerAdapter$PlayerItemViewHolder
08-27 15:57:03.421 19971-19971/? D/id: 0
08-27 15:57:03.421 19971-19971/? D/view_type: 2
08-27 15:57:03.421 19971-19971/? D/class: class io.github.nekotachi.easynews.ui.adapter.PlayerAdapter$PlayerItemViewHolder
```

Finally, it causes the error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Two different ViewHolders have the same stable ID. Stable IDs in your adapter MUST BE unique and SHOULD NOT change.
```

In this case, I think the view type should be same because they have same class. And also, the **id** should be different too.

Comment: You can use adapter.setHasStableIds(false), to prevent the error. However in case you are required to use ids [ they are used to prevent flickering effect], override getItemId method of your adapter and create a unique id of your own.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you're passing different `ViewType` for your views in the `RecyclerView` from `getItemViewType` function.

If you're returning different `ViewType` from `getItemViewType` then you need to handle the `ViewType` differently inside your `onBindViewHolder` along with having different `ViewHolder` types too.

For example, you've two different `ViewType`. This two can have same layout. But you need to specify a `ViewHolder` for each of them like this.

```
// For view_type = 1
private class FirstItemViewHolder extends ViewHolder {
    public FirstItemViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
    }
}

// For view_type = 2
private class SecondItemViewHolder extends ViewHolder {
    public SecondItemViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
    }
}
```

Now from your `getItemViewType` method you're returning the `ViewType` as usual.

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if(returnFirstViewType()){
        return VIEW_TYPE_1;
    } else {
        return VIEW_TYPE_2;
    }

    return super.getItemViewType(position);
}
```

Now when you are binding each view holder in your `onBindViewHolder` method, you need to check the `ViewType` first and then you need to take the other actions like this.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    try {
        if (holder instanceof FirstItemViewHolder) {
            FirstItemViewHolder vh = (FirstItemViewHolder) holder;
            // Code for view_type = 1 goes here

        } else {
            // Code for view_type = 2 goes here
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```